# ConditionalWeakTable/weak dictionary in Java or Scala

Tags: java, scala, dictionary, weak-references

In .NET, there is a class called [`ConditionalWeakTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757(v=vs.110).aspx). This is a map/dictionary that makes some guarantees about object lifetime and eligibility for garbage collection.

It holds weak references to keys, and automatically removes keys if they cannot be reached from anywhere outside the table (so keys aren't persisted by being members of the table, nor are they persisted if they can be reached from any other similarly unreachable key or value in the table, even if there are circular references and the like).

Values are still kept alive by the table, but they are removed if the key is removed because it is unreachable.

This class is used to attach properties to objects at runtime without causing memory leaks or interfering with garbage collection.

Is there a way to duplicate this kind of functionality in Java or Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use Java's [`WeakHashMap<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html):

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface, with weak keys.
>   An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key
>   is no longer in ordinary use. More precisely, the presence of a
>   mapping for a given key will not prevent the key from being discarded
>   by the garbage collector, that is, made finalizable, finalized, and
>   then reclaimed. When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively
>   removed from the map, so this class behaves somewhat differently from
>   other Map implementations.

Or if you're using Scala, use the wrapper provided by [`scala.collection.mutable.WeakHashMap[A,B]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.WeakHashMap)

Comment: Thank you! It is different in an important respect: "...Thus care should be taken to ensure that value objects do not strongly refer to their own keys" -- the .NET table deals with this situation automatically, but I guess it's good enough if there is nothing else.

Comment: You can wrap your values in a `WeakReference` to work around that, as specified in the other part of the docs: *If the values in the map do not rely on the map holding strong references to them, one way to deal with this is to wrap values themselves within WeakReferences before inserting.*

Comment: Ah, but that introduces another problem: Now values can die just like keys, and I don't want that. Properties aren't supposed to disappear by themselves.

Comment: I see, well, it's possible, just so you know :)